# soapUI service request not connecting

Tags: web-services, wsdl, soapui, soap-client

I recently installed soapUI for testing a webservice (later I will have to consume it in vb.net), do not have much experience consuming services from wsdl...

So I received a wsdl file, after importing into soapUI and firing a request this gives me:

> Wed Nov 05 11:16:10 CET 2014:ERROR:Exception in request: java.net.UnknownHostException: NLBAVWEBIZ1

After requesting a url for the wsdl file I instead received an ip and port:42424. When I enter these (preferences/proxy) in my existing project I get the following.

> ERROR:Exception in request: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:42424 refused

These errors seem to be quite clear, still I am worried I might be missing something obvious to get this to work?

**EDIT**:
Link to the wsdl file and ip:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/soitkj5oyu3ko0t/Orders.wsdl?dl=0
172.21.1.3:42424

Comment: Can you see the WSDL in just an ordinary browser?

Comment: No I get connection timeouts, but I am not sure my url format is correct, I have added the wsdl file and the ip, if someone else could give it a try..

Comment: No, I get same. Whomever is offering this service needs to give you access.

Comment: Thank you SiKing for checking this for me, the company that is providing the wsdl is an offshore company and I cannot contact them directly, only through my client, wanted to be sure. I cannot give you anything for just effort it seems :)

Comment: Glad you can move on with your project. Catch me next time. ;)